# How do I convert a string of comma separated integers to just comma separated ints for a ExecuteSql command?

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters, entity-framework-core, table-valued-parameters

I'm getting an exception because the ids are a string

> ex. '(1,2)'

I need it be comma separated but not a string, otherwise I get an exception saying:

> Exception Message: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int.

Code

```
var ids = string.Join(',', students.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray());
var studentResult = await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync($"UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Attended = Attended + 1, EditedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE Id IN ({ids})");
```

Here is what I see in the terminal

> [2023-08-03T19:29:26.800Z] Failed executing DbCommand (205ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1,4' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> [2023-08-03T19:29:26.801Z] UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Attended = Attended + 1, EditedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE Id IN ('@p0')
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z] AZURE FUNCTION: ServiceBusConsumer Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@p0' to data type int.
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z] Result: AZURE FUNCTION: ServiceBusConsumer Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@p0' to data type int.
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z] Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@p0' to data type int.
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z]    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z]    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z]    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> [2023-08-03T19:29:38.832Z]    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

If I add a Console.WriteLine like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Attended = Attended + 1, EditedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE Id IN ({ids})");
```

I see this (bottom line)

[image]

Comment: With EF Core 7, you can do that with simple `ExecuteUpdate`

Comment: Will executeupdate still run if I have a BeginTransactionAsync call?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the SQL this produces looks valid to me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qczq2q  When you debug, before invoking `ExecuteSqlAsync`, what is the runtime value of that interpolated string?

Comment: If I set a breakpoint and hover over ids, I see this -> "1,4" It's a string.

Comment: @chuckd: No, that *entire interpolated string* will not be `"1,4"`.  The value of `ids` may be, but the entire resulting string is not.  It sounds like you're making some mistakes and assumptions in your debugging.

Comment: I'll post what I see in the terminal above

Comment: give me a sec to run another test to see what the formattable string is. I'll post it when generated.

Comment: @chuckd: It's *very strange* to me that this `ExecuteSqlAsync` method is somehow preventing the string from being interpolated and is instead converting this to something parameterized.  I'd fully have expected that string interpolation to take place *before* passing the result of that interpolation to the method.  I'm also struggling to find the documentation for this `ExecuteSqlAsync` method.  I'm finding plenty of docs for similarly named methods, but not this exact one.  Do you have a reference to that?

Comment: If I add a Console.WriteLine() I see the image above.

Comment: @chuckd: That looks like valid SQL, and also has no `@p0` parameter.  It again sounds like there's a mistake in the debugging somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "mistake in the debugging"?

Comment: Can you put the SQL command into a variable, then pass the variable into the `ExecuteSqlAsync` call?  As I remember, string interpolation can be passed into functions as parts.

Comment: Give me a sec to do it. I'll post results of what I see.

Comment: @Trisped: Can it?  I've never seen that, though I guess it's never come up.  Things like logging systems use strings which *look like* interpolated strings but aren't (no `$` syntax) and take the arguments as variables.  Though JavaScript template literals do have a syntax for handling them in a function by their individual parts, so it's not unheard of for C# to have that as well.  But if the usage is the same syntax then that would be *very unintuitive* to me, because basically you'd have a situation where sometimes an expression is evaluated first and sometimes not.

Comment: @David - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#executing-non-querying-sql

Comment: FYI - there's a ExecuteSqlRawAsync and what I'm using ExecuteSqlAsync. The former seems to work!

Comment: @chuckd: That was very interesting, and I've learned something.  (And I still think it's unintuitive, but that's a soapbox for another day.)  It looks like the *key* difference here is the expected parameter type for that `ExecuteSqlAsync` method.  It's not accepting a string (which would interpolate before calling the method), but instead a `FormattableString` (new to me, thanks for the link) and does indeed internally perform "magic" to make these parameters.  Making it a raw string before calling the method would "work", but would negate the use of parameters and shouldn't be widely used.

Comment: @chuckd: Unfortunately my research has yet to turn up an example of parameterizing an `IN` clause in this syntax though...

Comment: @David: I'm looking to see if I can use an IN clause in an ExecuteUpdate for EF Core 7? According to the MS docs they say to use it whenever possible, instead of a ExecuteSql for bulk updates. I'm not really bulk updating, I'm passing in a couple of ids, but I'd like to stick with EF if possible and use sql as little as possible.

Comment: @chuckd: `ExecuteUpdate` may be the way to go, if I'm looking at the right docs for it. Perhaps something like: `_dbContext.AspNetUsers.Where(u => ids.Contains(u.id)).ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(u => u.Attended, u => u.Attended + 1).SetProperty(u => u.EditedDate, DateTime.UtcNow));`  This is *entirely* freehand and a guess based on what I've derived here.  You may need to pass `DateTime.UtcNow` as a variable declared before the query operation.  (And of course if you don't want to use `UtcNow`, use whatever you want.)  I'd start tinkering with that syntax and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteSql` will take your string interpolation and construct parameters out of it.

**You are making a fundamental mistake here:** SQL parameters are *not* injected into the query, they are *bound* to placeholders. In this case, the comma-separated string is just that: a string, not a number, and it can never be a number because it has commas in it.

Effectively your query has become `WHERE Id IN (@ids)` with a single string value, which is the same as `WHERE Id = @ids`. So it's obvious why this doesn't work.

What you need is to pass it in as separate values. There are number of ways to do this.

- Pass in the full array and hope that the EF Core can translate this (depends on provider). Usually this is done internally by passing separate parameters `WHERE Id IN (@id0, @id1)`. SQL Server has a maximum of 2100 parameters, but you will hit performance issues long before that.

```cs
var ids = students.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
var studentResult = await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlAsync(@$"
UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers
SET Attended = Attended + 1,
    EditedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE Id IN ({ids})");
```

- Insert the values into a table and join on it. This can get complicated if you have multiple queries hitting the database at the same time.
- The best option is probably to use a Table Valued Parameter.

First, create a Table Type in SSMS. I usually keep a few standard one and two column types for this purpose.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList (Value int PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you create an `SqlParameter` with a `DataTable` as the value. And pass that to `ExecuteSql`.

```cs
var table = new DataTable { Columns = {
    {"value", typeof(int)},
} };

foreach (var s in students)
    table.Rows.Add(s.Id);

var idParam = new SqlParameter("@ids", table) { TypeName = "dbo.IntList" };

var studentResult = await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(@"
UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers
SET Attended = Attended + 1,
    EditedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Value FROM @ids);
",
    idParam);
```

In EF Core 7.0+, you can also try both of these options using the new `ExecuteUpdate`, by composing over them.

```cs
var ids = students.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
var studentResult = await _dbContext.Set<Student>.FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE Id IN ({ids})
"
    ).ExecuteUpdateAsync(setter => setter
        .SetProperty(s => s.Attended, s => s.Attended + 1)
        .SetProperty(s => s.EditedDate, s => DateTime.Now)
    );
```

Alternatively using a TVP, you can fully compose the query:

```
var idQuery = _dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>(
    "SELECT Value FROM @ids",
    new SqlParameter("@ids", table) { TypeName = "dbo.IntList" }
);  // this is an IQueryable, nothing is executed yet

// must do this in a separate step, do not combine
var studentResult = await _dbContext.Set<Student>
    .Where(s => idQuery.Any(i => i == s.Id))
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setter => setter
        .SetProperty(s => s.Attended, s => s.Attended + 1)
        .SetProperty(s => s.EditedDate, s => DateTime.Now)
    );
```

This final option is probably the best.

---

Note that if you want a multi-column TVP then you cannot use `_dbContext.Database.SqlQuery`. Instead you need to map a full entity and use `Set<MyEntity>.FromSqlRaw`

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Thank you! I'm now using ExecuteUpdate.