# Expression tree to sql, Guid constants are translated to string in database and can't be read as Guid

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, ef-core-7.0

I have a method that returns some dynamic grouping keys:

```cs
private Expression<Func<T, object>> GetKeySelector<T>(Request req,
    Expression<Func<T, Guid>> domainKey, ...

// Gets called on a Queryable q.   
q.GroupBy(GetKeySelector<Order>(req, x => x.DomainId, ...

// Inside GekKeySelector, based on the request a key is picked:
if (...)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(domainKey.Body, typeof(object)), domainKey.Parameters);
}
```

There can be different key types so the return type is `ExpressionFunc<T, object>`.

I now want to add another grouping based on the domainKey which uses a translation list to build a if-then-else tree:

```cs
if (...)
{
    // List is of type 'a new { id, OrganizationId }
    var list = ...;

    Expression expr = Expression.Constant(Guid.Empty, typeof(Guid)); // Default value

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        expr = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(domainKey.Body, Expression.Constant(item.Id, typeof(Guid))),
            Expression.Constant(item.OrganizationId, typeof(Guid)), expr);
    }

    expr = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(Guid)); // Debugging attempt - did not help.
    
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(object)), domainKey.Parameters);
}
```

This kinda works and produces the following sql and expression:

```sql
    SELECT ... CASE
        WHEN [a].[DomainId] = '8255b5a1-b52f-4661-2571-08db5b57a880' THEN '32795fb3-27cf-45f1-c629-08db584be10a'
        ...
        WHEN [a].[DomainId] = 'cd9ad94d-1fcf-4738-46f2-08d94d0733d4' THEN 'eaf738b8-2c15-4d65-c225-08d94dbb2fb0'
        ELSE '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    END AS [Key]
```

```cs
.GroupBy(
        keySelector: x => (object)(Guid)x.DomainId == 8255b5a1-b52f-4661-2571-08db5b57a880 
? 32795fb3-27cf-45f1-c629-08db584be10a : x.DomainId == 93964c6b-7428-46e4-a0fd-08da38abb4e9 ... 
? eaf738b8-2c15-4d65-c225-08d94dbb2fb0 : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, 
        elementSelector: ...
```

When running the queryable we get an exception:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An error occurred while reading a database value. The expected type was 'System.Object' but the actual value was of type 'System.String'.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ThrowReadValueException[TValue](Exception exception, Object value, Type expectedType, IPropertyBase property)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.<ToListAsync>d__65`1.MoveNext()
   at [REDACTED]
  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Guid'.
```

I think the culprits here are the constants: `Expression.Constant(..., typeof(Guid))` which are translated to string (they should be something like `CAST(... as uniqueidentifier)` to match the expected value).

How can i solve this exception and have the generated sql return proper guids?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks like you should probably be using a Table Valued Parameter or other way of comparing in bulk. A giant `CASE` isn't really sustainable.

Comment: @Charlieface the case is only 15-20 items and other solutions would take considerable more work - its a niche case.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server it's really not difficult, and less code than what you have already. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538657/14868997 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/76831915/14868997

Comment: @Charlieface apologies, i meant it takes more work to wire such solutions in, i really only want to change the GetKeySelector method. I wasn't aware of tvp however I might use that in the future :)

Comment: @Charlieface well spotted, unfortunately that did not help. I'm guessing the ef core provider for mssql doesnt not translate guid's because they can be implicitly converted in sql server, wrapping the constants in `CAST(... AS uniqueidentifier)` would fix this.

Comment: If, as a test, you remove all the references to object and make everything guid-only, does it make any difference?

Comment: What about `return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Guid>>(expr, domainKey.Parameters);` instead of converting it on the last line