Why removal of column from index improved performance?
I'm quite puzzled with the issue I just solved. Yes, I have it solved, but I still don't understand why the fix worked.
So, I have a SQL Server table. Rather big one, on the scale of billions of rows. It has a clustered index on two columns A (~millions of unique values) and B (~thousands unique values). AxB combination is not unique. It also has regular index on B.
There is basically the only query this table has to serve, which boils down to selecting some millions of rows based on certain given values of A and B:
WHERE 
    A IN (a1, a2, ... aN) 
    AND B IN (b1, b2, ... bM)

It also groups and aggregates results, but that's unrelated to the topic.
Anyway, under certain conditions performance of this query drastically slows down. I.e. just on one server few of hundreds of tests we have would run for 15 minutes while others similar usually fit under 10 seconds. Analysis of execution plan shows that it actually was scanning cluster index for both A and B and was doing this billions of times. "Fast" executions in fact entirely ignored B in both clustered and secondary indices, just scanning for A.
Based on this information I removed column B from the clustered index, and got the tests fixed.
All machines in question are running SQL Server 2022 Developer edition (actually all of them were installed just a few days ago), statistics refreshed right prior to execution of tests, even more, databases are effectively read-only, restored from the same backup. Available memory and CPUs are different.
Hence the question(s): why removing the second column from the index actually improved query performance? To the best of my understanding, it should have only made things worse, yet apparently it made things better.
Why was the SQL Server:

ignoring that part of index in first place if it is actually present in both index and query? This index was designed with this query in mind and seems to be perfect for it. Or isn't it?

why when it was using it, it was slowing everything down by orders of magnitude?


P.S. Here is the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJJXnyFQC
P.P.S. Apparently, there is a detail I considered unimportant, yet it is: number of As and Bs queried is quite significant (tens of thousands and hundreds to thousands respectively), and I pass them as json string which is in turn parsed with OPENJSON (or rather Entity Framework Core does that for me).

Supplying the query, and the query plans (via Paste the Plan), will really help us help you here.

How large are the IN lists? Should certainly be possible in principle for SQL Server to convert that into N*M seeks on (A,B) rather than scan it.

@MartinSmith you are exactly right. N was something like 90000, and M 2200, resulting into 2 billion seeks.

@ThomA paln is added.

Ah - well 2 billion seeks could well be more expensive than just doing 90,000 seeks on A and a residual predicate on B to evaluate all the rows returned for the A part. Each seek has to start at the root and navigate the depth of the index

@MartinSmith that would be exactly my expectation. However for some reason SQL server decided against it.

It is explicitly documented that having such a large list [in the IN] is a bad idea, @AndriyK . Use an (indexed) table type parameter in an EXISTS if you must have that many

I am, honestly, surprised you didn't hit error 8623 with a list of 90,000 values in the IN.

@ThomA - The execution plan shows in reality they are from JSON not a long list

But SQL Server is going to have no idea how many values the JSON really contains so the estimated number of executions for the operators are garbage

That conflicts with the query they have in the question then, @MartinSmith . Though I do wonder how a JSON array would perform compared to an (indexed) Table Type Parameter.

With a table type parameter it can get better cardinality estimates if OPTION (RECOMPILE) is used or with deferred compilation so won't just assume 50 for both lists

@MartinSmith thank you, I was wondering why estimates were so off. That explains it.

@ThomA EF Core handily creates those JSON lists for me, and so far it worked just fine. Table type parameters might be giving better performance, however they are not that easy to work with from code side, so we'll have to assess if the gain is worth the expenses.

@ThomA OPENJSON gets a default 100 rows estimate, and the values are not assumed unique so it would get an extra Sort/Stream or Hash Aggregate

TVPs are not that difficult to use in EF Core, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/76831915/14868997 If you show your existing code we can show how to improve it. Either way, it's difficult/inefficient for it to use a single multi-column index for such a query, because both A and B predicates are OR. Your best bet might be two separate indexes and have it use an Index Union (basically querying twice and INTERSECTing).

@Charlieface thank you, your link has enough information for me to work with. I like index intersection idea, it might be just the right thing to do.

Personally I don't see any advantage over using the index intersection over just seeking on A and doing a residual predicate on B from a covering index. With the index intersection it still has to do all the A seeks and now has to join the result onto all of the B seeks. It's not like the combined result sets of the many seeks on A and of the many seeks on B are going to be ordered in any way that would facilitate joining them together via a merge join. If it is going to do a hash join it can equally well do that based on the B value pulled from the covering index

@MartinSmith your comments were spot on, it really boiled down to JSON strings and inability of analyzer to predict the number of items in them. If you can draft a quick answer, I'd gladly mark it as accepted.

Thanks to martin-smith comments it become clear that real culprit was OPENJSON that was used as a mean to pass large list of ids from Entity Framework Core down to SQL Server.
Apparently, Query Optimizer assumes only 50 elements in JSON, and when there are significantly more of them, execution plan starts having little common with reality.
Respectively removal of the column from the index removed the option to use it and Query Optimizer become forced to use "slower" execution plan, which is in fact way faster with the large number of items in JSONs.

Let's think of your query a little bit.
On the surface you are saying that

A is in (a1, a2, ..., aN) AND
B is in (b1, b2, ..., bM)

Let's think further:

(A = a1 OR A = a2 OR ... OR A = aN) AND
(B = b1 OR B = b2 OR ... OR B = bM)

Further:

(A = a1 AND (B = b1 OR B = b2 OR ... OR B = bM)) OR
(A = a2 AND (B = b1 OR B = b2 OR ... OR B = bM)) OR
...
(A = aN AND (B = b1 OR B = b2 OR ... OR B = bM)) OR

Therefore: we have N statements and for each of them we have M substatements.
Now, the second index, as you pointed out, was not of much use. And you wonder why? The reason largely depends on your exact situation. A frequent problem of indexes is

Index fragmentation occurs when the logical order of the pages in an index does not match the physical order on disk. This can cause SQL Server to perform more disk reads and page splits, degrade performance and increase disk space usage. You can use the ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE or ALTER INDEX REBUILD statements or the Index Defragmentation feature to reduce index fragmentation.

See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/top-10-sql-server-database-issues-can-slow-down-your-application-r-/
It's possible that simply too much disk movement was involved, losing a bit of performance per turn, but having too many turns, as you described the size of the problem.
It's also possible that simply too much possible B values were in the in and they were correlating to the clusters the index has for the given A value.
In general, the solution is to carefully study your index, its order and your query.

I have seen this answer has been down-voted. If I would find out what the reason was, what needs to be improved, then I would be happy to comply.

Sorry, it wasn't me who downvoted it. I think you are right. Trying to reproduce this issue I figured that there actually was some change to the offending instance, namely new batch of data added that was missing in other copies. That must have added to index fragmentation and caused the observed behavior.

The issue is nothing to do with fragmentation. It is just a bad execution plan. The execution plan shown  is doing 206,719,755 seeks on a table that only has 113,394,000 rows. This is just very inefficient. It estimates it will only do 353 such seeks because it has no idea what JSON it will be faced with and doesn't do any analysis of this when compiling the plan.
